# setting separation between columns in two column mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, columns

I'm using a two column article as in the link [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/521c086ae1f4b69204279f77). I'm new to LaTeX and am facing difficulty in setting the separation between the columns. I've read questions but all of them suggest to use `\setlength{\columnsep}{width}` I've used the same but the column separation does not change on any value. I suppose I'm going wrong with the dimensions. Please suggest where am I going wrong and what's the solution.

Comment: Sorry it's a typo in the question.

Comment: You are setting `0in` that means no space (0 inches). Try with `10pt` and increase it if it isn't enough. You also have to put it in the preamble...

Comment: I did try with 10pt also but nothing. But putting in the preamble helped. Thanks @karlkoeller.

Comment: effectively `10pt` is a bit too little to be seen... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cm` or `in` instead of font points to separate the columns:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{MWE}
\author{Dan}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Will produce:

[image: Column separation]

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61646/34355 for use of the `multicols` package.